# Unable to authenticate _csrf token based web application in OWASP ZAP zap-full-scan.py docker

Tags: owasp, zap

I am using `docker.io/owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-full-scan.py` to execute on a target.
Below is the jenkins pipeline script -

```
pipeline {

   agent { label master }

stages {
        stage ('Pull Docker Image') {
            steps {
     
                 sh 'docker images'
            }
        }
       
        stage ('Scan Host') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                  sh """sudo docker run -v /home/root/workspace/ZAP_docker/Reports:/zap/wrk/:rw -t docker.io/owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-full-scan.py \
                    -I -j -m 30 -T 60 \
                    -t https://${params.IP}:${params.PORT}/webui.* \
                    -d -r testreport.html \
                    -g gen.conf \
                    -z "auth.loginurl=https://${params.IP}:${params.PORT}/webui/login \
                        auth.username=${params.USERNAME} \
                        auth.password=${params.PASSWORD} \
                        auth.username_field="username" \
                        auth.password_field="password" \
                        auth.submit_field="login-btn"""
                    }
                }
            }
        stage ('Publish Report') {
            steps {
                 archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'logs/*, Reports/*', followSymlinks: false
                }
        }
        stage ('Send a Report') {
            steps {
                 office365ConnectorSend message: 'ZAP PROXY Report Alert!!!!', webhookUrl: 'dfdfDF'
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are my questions -

1. How can i clarify if the zap has logged into the application, or the login has been failed or the authentication has been failed.
2. My application has the csrf token based authentication

```
username=abc&password=abc&_csrf=4334345-435345354-435345345-2a-02c38a3d9e20
```

[image]

Now zap is not scanning with login auth.

I am able to perform end to end scan on OWASP ZAP desktop. However I want to automate this using jenkins pipeline.

Comment: You should reach out to ICTU their image is not supported by the core team.

Comment: Hmmmm https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68805913/revisions

Answer (score 0):

`-z` is for ZAP config options, which does not include:

```
                    -z "auth.loginurl=https://${params.IP}:${params.PORT}/webui/login \
                        auth.username=${params.USERNAME} \
                        auth.password=${params.PASSWORD} \
                        auth.username_field="username" \
                        auth.password_field="password" \
                        auth.submit_field="login-btn"""
```

<sub>^ those seem to be ICTU specific, and don't seem to include any logged in or logged out indicator ...</sub>

You could properly setup your Context via ZAP GUI, then export it and use it in your scan with the [options](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/full-scan/):

```
    -n context_file   context file which will be loaded prior to scanning the target
    -U user           username to use for authenticated scans - must be defined in the given context file (post 2.9.0)
```

Or you could configure things via the [ZAP Web API](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#introduction) and use custom scan [hooks](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/scan-hooks/) to leverage it.